# Control characters are not displayed in my terminal (e.g., when I press "^C")

Tags: terminal, signals, special-characters

My terminal does not display `^C` when I press <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> in my terminal.  I have tried setting various STTY options and am not sure what is wrong.

I am running Mac OSX 10.11.16 and this phenomenon occurs in the Terminal app as well as the iTerm2 terminal emulator.  I am not sure where I am going wrong.  Here is the output of `stty -a`:

```
speed 38400 baud; 39 rows; 171 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel -iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Comment: With newer `bash` versions, it's subject to the `echo-control-characters` readline option. It's enabled by default, place `set echo-control-characters off` in `~/.inputrc` to disable printing that `^C`. Other apps might have their own settings. Simple utilities using the terminal's "cooked" mode rely on `stty [-]echoctl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the software, and is not consistent. Some shells will merely advance the prompt, others will show the desired `^C` (and possibly then exit), and others will emit something besides `^C`:

```
%
%
% tclsh
tclsh> ^C
% clisp
[1]> 
*** - Ctrl-C: User break

[2]> 
% perl -MTerm::ReadKey -E 'ReadMode "raw"; $k=ReadKey(0);' \
  -E 'say "control+c" if $k eq "\003"; ReadMode "restore"'
control+c
%
```

Comment: This ended up being correct: I updated to Bash 4.4 (from 3.x) and it is displaying "^C" now.